# Function such that $f(x) f(\pi/2 - x) = 1$

Tags: functions, functional-equations

I'm looking for functions that are smooth ($C^\infty$) between $0 < x < \pi/2$ that satisfy the equation
$$f(x)\, f(\pi/2-x) = 1$$
on the inteverval $0<x<\pi/2$. 
I know that the constant function $f=1$ satisfies this equation, as well as $f=\tan(x)$.  Are these the only solutions?

====

It seems that there are infinitely many $C^\infty$ functions that work, so long as the power series at $x=\pi/4$ is consistent with the restrictions coming from taking derivatives of the above expression at $\pi/4$.  Each of these power series should correspond to an analytic function that satisfies the above equation in a neighborhood of $x=\pi/4$.  So the question seems to be how many analytic solutions are there to the above problem?

Comment: Also $f(x) = -1$ and $-\tan(x)$. Others ...?

Comment: $\pm\tan x$ fails for $x=0$

Comment: There are infinitely many such functions even assuming continuity and differentiability - just choose $f(x)$ bounded away from zero on $0\leq x\leq\frac\pi4$, with $f(\frac\pi4)=\pm 1$ and an appropriate value for $f'(\frac\pi4)$, and then define $f(y)$ on $\frac\pi4\leq y\leq\frac\pi2$ using $f(y)=\frac1{f(\frac\pi2-y)}$.

Comment: @StevenStadnicki You only define $f(x)$ on $0\le x\le \pi/2$

Comment: @KristofferRyhl oh whoops, I should probably say that it doesn't have to hold at $x=0$ since I want to allow $f$ to diverge as $x\rightarrow \pi/2$.

Comment: @StevenStadnicki Are you sure this implies smoothness of the function at $\pi/4$?  I'm not seeing it immediately...

Comment: I changed the interval to $0<x<\pi/2$, I think it makes more sense that way.

Comment: @asperanz I just added a community wiki answer addressing the smoothness at $\pi/4$, and I don't think there really is a condition on the $f$ derivative there.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Taking the logarithm gives
$$
\log f(x)+\log f(\pi/2 - x)=0,
$$
or
$$
\log f\left(\pi/4 + (x-\pi/4)\right)=-\log f\left(\pi/4 - (x - \pi/4)\right).
$$
That is, $\log f$ needs to be odd under reflection across $\pi/4$.  So let $g(x)$ be any odd function (defined at least for $|x|<\pi/4$); then
$$
f(x)=\exp{g(x - \pi/4)}
$$
meets the conditions.  If $g(x)$ is chosen to be continuous, smooth, or analytic, then $f(x)$ will be an equally "nice" function.  For instance, $f(x)=e^{x-\pi/4}$ is a simple analytic example, or $f(x)=e^{(x-\pi/4)^3}$.

Answer (score 3):

Rescaling the interval to $(0,2),$ we want $f(x)f(2-x)=1$. Assuming this $f$ is smooth, and say $f(1)=1$ [one of the two choices there], let $g(x)$ be its restriction to $[0,1]$, and then on $[1,2]$ we have $f(x)=h(x) \equiv 1/g(2-x).$ The derivative matching is automatic:
$$h'(x)=\frac{-1}{g(2-x)^2}g'(2-x)\cdot (-1),$$
which since $g(1)=1$ and $g'(2-1)=g'(1),$ gives a match between the left side derivative of $g$ at $x=1$ and the right side derivative of $h$ at $1.$

So it seems $f$ may be chosen arbitrarily nonzero on $(0,1]$ with $f$ smooth on a on that interval (derivative from the left at $1$ existing), and then extended to all of $(0,2)$ as noted.

This is essentially the same as Steven Stadniki's comment, just extended to show there is really no derivative matching issue. [So I made it community wiki.]

Comment: by smooth I mean $C^\infty$.  Looking at the second derivative at $x=pi/4$ (or I guess $1$ in your example) I think gives a nontrivial restriction on the function at that point, $f''-(f')^2=0$.  Higher derivatives give still more restrictions, and I'm wondering if $tan(x)$ and the constant function are the unique solutions satisfying all these smoothness conditions.

Comment: @asperanz $C^\infty$ doesn't restrict things much - you can use a smooth bump function with finite support to ensure that _all_ derivatives work at the midpoint (and in fact, even say that all derivatives are zero there) and still get arbitrary behavior away from there.

Comment: @StevenStadnicki okay, I see.  However, I have to choose the $C^\infty$ function such that its power series works at the midpoint.  Setting all the derivatives to zero is like making it locally the constant function, and I could also locally make it match a $\tan$ function.  Maybe I should have asked for how many analytic functions satisfy the requirement, since each analytic function would characterize the type of power series the $C^\infty$ function can have at the midpoint.

Comment: @asperanz To insist on power series for the function is to require it be analytic. In that case there is very little room for readjustment near the midpoint.